# Cloning mysql installation

Tags: mysql

I need to move a mysql installation to another computer, can I just copy files?
It is vers 4.1, I installed it and copied database but couldn't access it by the program I need. And if I connect to old comp it works fine.

So I need it to be just like on the old one

Comment: 4.1?!?  Plan on getting off it pronto!

Comment: Why?? I use it only for that program, works fine by now

Comment: @Rick James i need to use 4.1 cos of this program I use, is there some problem with it??

Comment: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."  However, there may come a day when it won't work on the latest OS (or whatever); at that point, the update path could be somewhere between difficult and impossible.  Maybe you just found that case?

Comment: @Rick Planning to put it on a virtual machine, so not to depend on OS, just have to move it on another comp first...

Comment: Good luck.  a_vlad's answer is probably good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full list of steps very depends - what OS (source and target)? 
Generally You can copy mysql between 100% similar computers, but You are must copy ALL folders and after - or start mysql manually or manually add MySQL to run as Windows / Linux service.

More easy ways:

1. If computer Similar - You can install MySQL from installation package and then copy only data folder (name and location depend from OS)
2. If computer different (like Windows -> Linux) - You can install MySQL on target computer, on Source computer dump all data using mysqldump, on Target computer make restore from dump using command line client

Comment: I guess I am missing that OS integration as you said, the windows service. Don't really know what are 100% similar computers, both are windows7. But I see difference in data folder, there are some files named by comp user, which differes from one to another computer, may that be the problem?

Comment: To be 100% sure - install MySQL by installer, after this You can 1) copy C:\Program Data\mysqlXXX\data between computers 2) use dump/restore - this is 100% success way